# way2sms API for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, sms

I am trying a sample application for sending sms from rails application ( from pc to mobile). Are there any tutorials for using api's like that of "way2sms" website ? And any suggestion of getting the same api?

I referred this site http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2009/07/way2sms-api.html

Thanks!

Comment: search & use for clickatell.but it's not free :(

Comment: thank you for your help but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sending SMS is usually not FREE. At least not when you want to use an API for it. It also varies depending on your demographic. Are you inside US only? If so there is also [Moonshado](http://moonshado.com/) which is used as Addon in Heroku, sounds good, but not free as well.

Comment: but can u give me a way2sms api for rails application.

Comment: @jayesh hope that will help [https://github.com/meetme2meat/Way2SMS-Ruby-Code](https://github.com/meetme2meat/Way2SMS-Ruby-Code)